# Brute force graph transformations

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have a list of list of pairs of integer that for me represents a list of graphs with `n` nodes.
For example with `n=5` I could have

```
graphs = {
{{1,2},{3,4},{3,5}},
{{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,3}},
{{2,3},{2,4}},
{{3,4},{3,5},{4,5}}
};
```

Now I'm interested in finding, for each pair of them, what is the number of way you can map the nodes of one onto the nodes of the other under a particular condition.
The condition is that if two nodes are connected in the starting graph, they can't be connected in the ending graph.
This is a first naive implementation

```
Table[
  Count[Intersection[graphs[[i]], #] & /@
    Map[Sort, 
      ReplaceAll[graphs[[j]], #] & /@ (MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Range@5, #}] & /@ Permutations@Range@5), 
    {2}],
  {}],
{i, Length@graphs}, {j, i}]
```

Imagine working with bigger and more graphs, it slows down very quickly and any kind of optimization is much needed.
I thought that it can be way better to precalculate one pure function for each graph instead of creating the list of replacement rules each time. I've done so

```
graphfunctions = Function /@ (Map[ToExpression["#" <> ToString@#] &, #, {2}] & /@ graphs);
searchspace = Permutations@Range@5;

Table[
  Count[Intersection[graphs[[i]], #] & /@
    Map[Sort, 
      graphfunctions[[j]] @@@ searchspace), 
    {2}],
  {}],
{i, Length@graphs}, {j, i}]
```

My questions are:

- Given the fact that I'm interested in empty intersections can `Intersection` be properly short circuited? I've tried using `AnyTrue` with `MemberQ` but it isn't faster.
- Is `Sort` still the fastest way to swap two element if they are in reverse order?
- Do I really need to order the pairs or could there be a custom function that does "unordered" and short circuited intersection that is faster than `Intersection` and `Sort`?
- How can `Sort` be put directly inside the pure graph functions? Maybe it would be slightly faster than mapping it later
- Did I miss something that can be optimized?

Answer (score 1):

I was fiddling around my first time with Mathematica compiler, trying a bunch of variations of `graphfunctions`, when I had a nice idea to bypass `Sort` and even unburden `Intersection`...
First, for this problem using one argument instead of many is better, both for the uncompiled and compiled function

```
graph = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}};
searchspace = Permutations@Range@7;
gf1 = {{#1, #2}, {#1, #3}, {#1, #4}, {#2, #3}, {#2, #4}, {#3, #4}, {#2, #5}, {#3, #5}, {#4, #5}, {#4, #6}, {#4, #7}, {#5, #6}, {#5, #7}, {#6, #7}} &;
gf2 = {{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, {#[[1]], #[[3]]}, {#[[1]], #[[4]]}, {#[[2]], #[[3]]}, {#[[2]], #[[4]]}, {#[[3]], #[[4]]}, {#[[2]], #[[5]]}, {#[[3]], #[[5]]}, {#[[4]], #[[5]]}, {#[[4]], #[[6]]}, {#[[4]], #[[7]]}, {#[[5]], #[[6]]}, {#[[5]], #[[7]]}, {#[[6]], #[[7]]}} &;
cgf1 = Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}, {c, _Integer}, {d, _Integer}, {e, _Integer}, {f, _Integer}, {g, _Integer}}, {{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c, d}, {b, e}, {c, e}, {d, e}, {d, f}, {d, g}, {e, f}, {e, g}, {f, g}}];
cgf2 = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}}, {{a[[1]], a[[2]]}, {a[[1]], a[[3]]}, {a[[1]], a[[4]]}, {a[[2]], a[[3]]}, {a[[2]], a[[4]]}, {a[[3]], a[[4]]}, {a[[2]],a[[5]]}, {a[[3]], a[[5]]}, {a[[4]], a[[5]]}, {a[[4]], a[[6]]}, {a[[4]], a[[7]]}, {a[[5]], a[[6]]}, {a[[5]], a[[7]]}, {a[[6]], a[[7]]}}];

gf1 @@@ searchspace; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.010304    *)

gf2 /@ searchspace; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.00741315    *)

cgf1 @@@ searchspace; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0049784    *)

cgf2 /@ searchspace; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.00170199    *)
```

Enclosing `Sort` in the compiled function seems to be a bad move

```
Map[Sort, gf2 /@ searchspace, {2}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0170787    *)

Map[Sort, cgf2 /@ searchspace, {2}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0117649    *)

cgf2sort = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}}, Sort /@ {{a[[1]], a[[2]]}, {a[[1]], a[[3]]}, {a[[1]], a[[4]]}, {a[[2]], a[[3]]}, {a[[2]], a[[4]]}, {a[[3]], a[[4]]}, {a[[2]], a[[5]]}, {a[[3]], a[[5]]}, {a[[4]], a[[5]]}, {a[[4]], a[[6]]}, {a[[4]], a[[7]]}, {a[[5]], a[[6]]}, {a[[5]], a[[7]]}, {a[[6]], a[[7]]}}];
cgf2sort /@ searchspace; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0131931    *)
```

Also, how can this happen?

```
c2sort1 = Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}}, If[a < b, {a, b}, {b, a}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
c2sort2 = Compile[{{x, _Integer, 1}}, If[x[[1]] < x[[2]], x, {x[[2]], x[[1]]}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

c2sort1 @@ {2, 1} // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    1.2205*10^-6    *)

c2sort2@{2, 1} // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    9.78707*10^-7    *)

Sort@{2, 1} // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    1.57242*10^-7    *)
```

By the way we can do without `Sort`, the interesting idea is to take advantage of the "undirectionality" of the graphs I'm treating.
If I could encode unambiguously and in a commutative way the pair of nodes that subtend an edge, I can have a single number for that edge ready to be searched as is. Prime numbers are what immediately comes to mind...

```
gfprime = With[{p = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17}}, {p[[#[[1]]]]*p[[#[[2]]]], p[[#[[1]]]]*p[[#[[3]]]], p[[#[[1]]]]*p[[#[[4]]]], p[[#[[2]]]]*p[[#[[3]]]], p[[#[[2]]]]*p[[#[[4]]]], p[[#[[3]]]]*p[[#[[4]]]], p[[#[[2]]]]*p[[#[[5]]]], p[[#[[3]]]]*p[[#[[5]]]], p[[#[[4]]]]*p[[#[[5]]]], p[[#[[4]]]]*p[[#[[6]]]], p[[#[[4]]]]*p[[#[[7]]]], p[[#[[5]]]]*p[[#[[6]]]], p[[#[[5]]]]*p[[#[[7]]]], p[[#[[6]]]]*p[[#[[7]]]]}] &;
cgfprime = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}}, With[{p = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17}}, {p[[a[[1]]]]*p[[a[[2]]]], p[[a[[1]]]]*p[[a[[3]]]], p[[a[[1]]]]*p[[a[[4]]]], p[[a[[2]]]]*p[[a[[3]]]], p[[a[[2]]]]*p[[a[[4]]]], p[[a[[3]]]]*p[[a[[4]]]], p[[a[[2]]]]*p[[a[[5]]]], p[[a[[3]]]]*p[[a[[5]]]], p[[a[[4]]]]*p[[a[[5]]]], p[[a[[4]]]]*p[[a[[6]]]], p[[a[[4]]]]*p[[a[[7]]]], p[[a[[5]]]]*p[[a[[6]]]], p[[a[[5]]]]*p[[a[[7]]]], p[[a[[6]]]]*p[[a[[7]]]]}]];
graphprime = cgfprime@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

Count[Intersection[graph, #] & /@ Map[Sort, gf2 /@ searchspace, {2}], {}] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0372562    *)

Count[Intersection[graph, #] & /@ Map[Sort, cgf2 /@ searchspace, {2}], {}] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0311057    *)

Count[Intersection[graphprime, #] & /@ (gfprime /@ searchspace), {}] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.019155    *)

Count[Intersection[graphprime, #] & /@ (cgfprime /@ searchspace), {}] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0121206    *)
```

### Original approach - Top optimization

...but are primes necessary? Do we need to bring up multiplication? Maybe we can construct [a sequence of integers for which the pairwise **sums** are all distinct](https://oeis.org/A005282)

```
cgfMian = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}}, With[{p = {1, 2, 4, 8, 13, 21, 31}}, {p[[a[[1]]]] + p[[a[[2]]]], p[[a[[1]]]] + p[[a[[3]]]], p[[a[[1]]]] + p[[a[[4]]]], p[[a[[2]]]] + p[[a[[3]]]], p[[a[[2]]]] + p[[a[[4]]]], p[[a[[3]]]] + p[[a[[4]]]], p[[a[[2]]]] + p[[a[[5]]]], p[[a[[3]]]] + p[[a[[5]]]], p[[a[[4]]]] + p[[a[[5]]]], p[[a[[4]]]] + p[[a[[6]]]], p[[a[[4]]]] + p[[a[[7]]]], p[[a[[5]]]] + p[[a[[6]]]], p[[a[[5]]]] + p[[a[[7]]]], p[[a[[6]]]] + p[[a[[7]]]]}]];
graphMian = cgfMian@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

Count[Intersection[graph, #] & /@ Map[Sort, gf1 @@@ searchspace, {2}], {}] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0476533    *)

Count[Intersection[graphMian, #] & /@ (cgfMian /@ searchspace), {}] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.0118117    *)
```

*Of course each of these compiled function can be set `Listable` for parallelization.*

My question on whether `Intersection` can be short circuited remains open although not as relevant.
Now my concern becomes: what's the Mathematica correct way of dynamically generete a list of `cgfMian` from a list of graphs?